# Sigmoid function symmetry property

Tags: symmetric-functions

In Wikipedia, I found the symmetry equation for a sigmoid function as $g(x) + g(-x) = 1$, where $g(x) = 1/1 + \exp(-x)$.

As per the property stated above, $g(x)$ becomes a symmetric function. But, algebraically, a function is said to be symmetric if and only if $g(-x) = g(x)$ or $g(-x) = -g(x)$ for even and odd symmetric respectively.

Can somebody clarify how sigmoid function is symmetric?

Thank you!

Comment: The function you are taking is called a logistic curve. This may help you find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the *algebraic* sense, symmetric means what you have stated: $g(x)=-g(x)$ or $g(x)=-g(-x)$.  In the *geometric* sense, something is symmetric if it looks the same after a particular sequence of flips, rotations, and translations.  The plot of the sigmoid function has point symmetry: if you rotate it 180 degrees around the point $(0,0.5)$ then it looks the same as it originally did.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $f(x) = g(x) - \frac{1}{2}$ is an odd function, equivalently the graph of $y=g(x)$ is rotationally symmetric about the point $(0, \frac{1}{2})$. Beyond that, it's not fair to say the sigmoid function is symmetric.